# Limit (Cut-off) number returned by function 'count(*)' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try this in MySQL:

> select make,count(*) as num from TABLE where num > 100  group by
>   make

I got:

```
Error Code: 1054, SQL State: 42S22]  Unknown column 'num' in 'where clause'
```

Is there a way to limit count(*)?

Comment: Use `having`, not `where`.

Comment: I'd say HAVING is for aggregate function conditions. Do a derived table instead, put condition outside.

Comment: `select make,count(*) as num from TABLE GROUP BY make HAVING count(*) > 100`

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff! Add 'having num>100' works!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put column aliasas in the `WHERE` clause. Use a derived table instead:

```
select make, num
from
(
    select make,count(*) as num from TABLE  group by make
) dt
where num > 100
```